# Replacing two lines in the terminal using Java

Tags: java, io

I know how to use Java to have output in the terminal be contained in one line by replacing the previous line. For example:

```
System.out.print("old line");
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.print("\rnew line");
```

But what if I have two lines of output and I want both replaced

```
/* array must have length divisible by 2 */
public void doPrinting(String[] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i*2]);
        System.out.println(array[i*2+1]);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //I imagine some fancy ascii crypticness shall go here?
    }
```

So, if I call `doPrinting(new String[]{"Old1", "Old2", "New1", "New2"})`, this should look like, in the Mac terminal:

```
MyName$ java MyClass
Old1
Old2
```

and then pause for 3 seconds, and then look like

```
MyName$ java MyClass
New1
New2
```

How can I do this? I'm on Mac OS and am running my Java main method through the terminal. The ideal answer would add code to modify the `doPrinting` method above.

---

UPDATE: After one answer from below, I tried this:

```
String ANSI_CSI = "\\x1b[";
String[] array = {"old1","old2","new1","new2"};
System.out.print("\n\n");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
    System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "2A"); // Up 2
    System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "K");  // Clear
    System.out.println(array[i*2]);
    System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "K");  // Clear
    System.out.println(array[i*2+1]);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
 }
```

but that just gives me this output in the terminal

```
MyName$ MyClass


\x1b[2A\x1b[Kold1
\x1b[Kold2
\x1b[2A\x1b[Knew1
\x1b[Knew2
```

Comment: Without knowledge of your environment, this is difficult to answer - the answer below assumes ANSI, but if you have a different kind of terminal/emulator/putty installation it may or may not work.

Comment: @KevinDTimm In my experience, all of the linux terminals and PuTTY support ANSI **better** than `cmd`.

Comment: If the user is using linux or windows - that's not stated anywhere

Comment: Sorry. Just added. I'm on Mac OS and am running my Java class through terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use [ANSI Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Here, you'll probably be interested in "Move Cursor Up" (`CSI-A`) and "Erase line" (`CSI-K`).

```
// outside code
public static final String ANSI_CSI = "\u001b[";
// inside code
System.out.println("First line of text");
System.out.println("[  5/365]");
System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "2A"); // up 2 lines
System.out.println("Different first line of text");
System.out.println("[ 11/365)");
System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "A"); // up line
System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "2K"); // erase all of line
System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "A"); // up line
System.out.print(ANSI_CSI + "K"); // erase after cursor
System.out.println("Line one");
System.out.println("[240/365]");
```

If you want to do this in a loop (`System.out` has been omitted for brevity):

```
// Init to safe state
print("\n\n");
for (loop conditions here) {
  print(ANSI_CSI + "2A"); // Up 2
  print(ANSI_CSI + "K");  // Clear
  println(text_a);        // Print + newline
  print(ANSI_CSI + "K");  // Clear
  println(text_b);        // Print + newline
  Thread.sleep(3000);     // Wait
}
```

Note that you're going to need to use a terminal that supports these. Check the Wikipedia article for more information. If it says that a certain code has different behavior under "ANSI.SYS", then that applies to the default Windows command prompt.

I don't have any experience with Macs, so your experience may vary with different terminals.

Most alternate and UNIX terminals (gnome-terminal, PuTTY) support these codes more fully (see the notes about `xterm`'s full RGB support).

Comment: Sorry, but is ANSI a Java class or something? I'm on Mac OS and am running my Java class through the terminal command "java MyClass"

Comment: And also, could you restructure the code to take the form of how I've included it in the question statement. Notice the loop structure.

Comment: Oh, derp. ANSI, for me, was a custom class that contained utility methods.

Comment: @CodeGuy Updated the answer with code specific to your situation

Comment: thanks, but there is an error on this line public static final String ANSI_CSI = "\x1b["; and I tried to change it to "\\x1b[" but then it prints with all those weird characters and doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @CodeGuy, it looks like if you use the unicode equivalent (starts with `\u`) rather than the ASCII encoding (starts with `\x`) it works. What I ended up doing was `String ANSI_CSI = "\u001b[";` which worked like a charm!

Comment: Too late to answer
But I think that \x is \u