# Let user select multiple elements in cmd

Tags: java, cmd

I am in the process of developing a command line application (cmd.exe) with Java and need an input mask in which the user can select several elements of a list with the arrow keys and select or deselect them with the space bar.

I need something like

```
Select elements:

( ) element 1
(*) element 2
( ) element 3
(*) element 4
(*) element 5
```

Do I have to overwrite every line as soon as an input is detected or can I solve it differently?

Edit: 
I know how to rewrite lines in the terminal and that is not what my question is about. I'm wondering if there is another solution!

Comment: @ButiriDan No, it's not. My question is whether I should use the technique you mentioned or if there is another (better) solution for my problem.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I deleted the comment. I used only this method [Replacing two lines in the terminal using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233956/replacing-two-lines-in-the-terminal-using-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some libraries, that provide such functionality like:

- [javacurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)
- [lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna)

Comment: The libraries bartel mention can track what has changed since the last screen refresh and will output the minimum needed to correctly update the screen. The answer to your question is use the library or track the changes yourself (I.e. where the asterisk was and where it is now) and only output that information to reflect the current position of the asterisk.